# Is there another way to run this PHP query without AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

In my `product.php` I give the user the opportunity to add or remove a deal in his wishlist.
I did it using AJAX and an external file that added his `id` and `product id`  but I don't want it with AJAX.

What is another way to run this SQL query in PHP when a button or a link or image is clicked? I don't mind if the page is refreshed.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM relations WHERE user_id = '$myid' and deal_id = '$dealid'";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
```

Comment: If you do not want to refresh the page, the best way is to use ajax request.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Why don't you want AJAX?

Comment: @SLaks Which is my SQL injection problem?

Comment: @mtopia Your SQL injection problem is embedding variables in the SQL string without casting it to an int (if it's a number) or adding SQL escaping to the contents (if it's a string). if you get this stuff wrong, you will allow a hacker to gain access to your database.

Comment: The question seems a bit confusing.  Are you really using AJAX but have no idea of regular forms using POST and GET method to send data on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple link?

```
<a href="delete-deal.php?dealid=42">Delete</a>
```

delete.php would look like something this:

```
<?php

/* mysql connection code here */

$myid = /* get myid somehow */
$dealid = (int)$_GET['dealid'];

$query = "DELETE FROM relations WHERE user_id = '$myid' and deal_id = '$dealid'";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();

header('Location: http://example.com/page/to/go/back/to');
```

Comment: Hm.. I didn't think about the `header('');`. How do I prevent users of going directly to this file though ?

Comment: You can't prevent users from directly going to the file. What you should do is check if the person going to the file is logged into a user account which has permission to delete the record.

Comment: **No**.  Do not perform destructive actions in a GET.  Do not allow the Googlebot to delete your site.

Comment: The googlebot usually doesn't have access to pages which can do actions like these. And while it's true that POST should ideally be used for a delete action, HTML does not provide any good way to perform a POST request. So, the pragmatic solution is to just use GET. A page with 3,000 <form> tags is *not* a good alternative in my opinion.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Why not?  You could also use a single `<form>` with differently-named submits.

Comment: Using forms adds complexity to the page with no real world benefit. We have worked on several hundred websites, using <a> tags for delete with all of them, and never had any problems. And if the shit does hit the fan, we've got backups.

Comment: **never use GET request** to alter your database. its POST for this purpose. google is nopt the only crawler. your browser can load some pages as well.

Comment: LOL. the "we never had any problems" reminds me the typical answer about SQL injections. It's exactly the same: "we never had any problems". Yet.

Comment: I challenge you to find a browser that causes problems. We have never come across one, in more than ten years of development and thousands of clients. Contrast that to SQL injections, which is something we come across regularly (usually not in any of our own code, touch wood)